# SQS SendMessageBatch Partial Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to send messages to SQS in Batch. I had a look at the API and it seems [SendMessageBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html) will work here.
However one thing I am not able to fully understand is it returns a List of [BatchResultErrorEntry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_BatchResultErrorEntry.html) in case of partial failure.

The AWS docs don't mention whether these are meant to be retried or just for the sake of information.
If these are meant to be retried will there be a risk of getting into an infinite loop if the same items fail again ? In this case should we identify the items out of the failed ones which can be safely retried based on the `Code`. Also it looks like since the failed message itself is not returned back we would have to maintain a mapping of the Batch`Id` to the Message to resend the message.

Or is the best practise here to log these and throw an Exception to the caller that these items failed.

Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Those are meant to be retried using the [exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) strategy.

Comment: How to know which of those to safely retry ?